# rails - Case Insensitive Search Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have the following:

```
  @users = User.find( :all,
                      :select => 'users.*',
                      :conditions => ["fname || ' ' || lname LIKE ?", '%'+"#{params[:q]}"+'%']
```

Problem here is that the search input params[:q] is case sensitive. How can I make it case insensitive in my Rails 3 Heroku app?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For PostgreSQL to get case insensitive LIKE just use `ILIKE`. It works according to the active locale.

Comment: Any special indexes needed to make this run smoothly? Any indexes at all for that matter?

Comment: @AnApprentice: it'll work just fine, but ILIKE is not an indexable operator. If you need indexed access, see polarblaus suggestion about using upper() and regular LIKE, which can be made indexable.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to index a LIKE statement beginning with % (match any content). And first part of statement is variable - needs separate expression-based index. To find how your schema is performing execute query with `EXPLAIN` prepended.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly "common" workaround for this problem seems to be to use the `UPPER` function to convert in your case "fname" or "lname" into uppercase and convert `params[:q]` as well, using e.g. `upcase`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively... stick this in your model and call by passing in a string array

```
def self.find_all_by_lowercasing_name(str_array)
    wrapped = str_array.collect { |a| "'"+ "#{a.downcase}" + "'" }
    return MyModel.where("lower(\"my_models\".\"name\") IN (#{wrapped.join(', ')})")
end
```

The above works with Postgres and Sqlite